# installing 340.29 driver along with cuda 6.0

Tags: cuda

I have recently installed cuda 6.0 with a view of performance increment in windows 7 . the toolkit installer has display driver installer along with it and it installed display driver version named as 9.18.13.4062 . is this version mean 340.62???

Also it is mentioned that driver version 340.29 with cuda increases performance according to this [link](http://www.techenablement.com/cuda-6-5-and-340-29-driver-significantly-boosts-gpu-performance/)

does 340.xx series have the same performance ?? I couldnot get the version 340.29 driver. where can i download it from???

Answer (score 2):

340.62 is the Windows GPU driver that ships with the CUDA 6.5 (windows) installer.

340.29 is the Linux GPU driver that ships with the CUDA 6.5 (linux) installer.

The link you have provided is referring to linux.  340.62 and 340.29 should be comparable, as much as "comparable" can be stated about a windows platform vs. a linux platform

Regarding the performance in the article linked, CUDA 6.5 (i.e. not just the driver) has significant performance increases in various libraries and in the compiler as well.

To get an idea of these performance increases, there is a webinar you can attend tomorrow (wednesday, September 17th) by following the link [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/760148/cuda-6-5-production-release-now-available/).